# C++ ifstream pointer open files fails

Tags: c++, ifstream

It seems like `ifstream*->open` doesn't work as I expected...
Here is the code: ( compiled with `g++ 4.7` using `-std=c++11` in `MAC OSX 10.7`)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string line;
    vector<string> fname = {"a.txt","b.txt"};
    vector<ifstream*> files ( 2, new ifstream );

    files[0]->open( fname[0] );
    getline( *files[0], line,  '\n');
    cerr<<"a.txt: "<<line<<endl; 
    //this one prints the first line of a.txt

    line.clear();

    files[1]->open( fname[1] );
    getline( *files[1], line, '\n'); 

    cerr<<"b.txt: "<<line<<endl;
    //but this one fails to print any from b.txt
    //actually, b.txt is not opened!

    return 0;
}
```

Can any one tell me what is wrong here???

Comment: You realize that none of those files are being closed properly because you are storing pointers to dynamically allocated streams and not calling `delete` on them, right?

Comment: Do you mean `ifstream->open` instead of `ifstream*->open` which implies two de-references of the pointer (implied) by `ifstream`?  Asked instead of edited to get answer.

Answer (score 5):

This executes `new std::ifstream` once where used, not once per `2` values you requested.

The `new std::ifstream` creates an ifstream pointer whose pointer value is inserted two times in `files` by the `std::ifstream` constructor.

`std::vector` takes care of only the objects it contains, which in this case are `ifstream*` pointers.  So, the `2` copies the pointer value.  When `files` falls out of scope, the pointers (and supporting data in the vector) are taken care of, but not the values the pointers point to.  As such, vector does not delete your new `std::ifstream` object (placed in the vector twice).

`operator delete` is not called for you because pointers can have many uses which cannot be determined easily.  One of which is to put the same pointer in the vector twice *on purpose*.